# Accurately calculate reserves by output amount

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, decentralized-exchange

Assume we are trading two tokens, A and B. The formula to calculate the amount of output B tokens that we can get for a given amount of input A tokens is calculated as following (From Uniswap and Pancakeswap):

```
amountOut = reserveOut * amountIn * 9975 / (reserveIn * 10000 + amountIn * 9975)
```

The above was derived from the *getAmountOut* function of PancakeSwap's router contract, which is the following:

```
function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountOut) {
    require(amountIn > 0, 'PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
    require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
    uint amountInWithFee = amountIn.mul(9975);
    uint numerator = amountInWithFee.mul(reserveOut);
    uint denominator = reserveIn.mul(10000).add(amountInWithFee);
    amountOut = numerator / denominator;
}
```

Given an **amountOut** value and an **amountIn** value, how can we get the respective **reserveIn** and **reserveOut**?

This will answer the question of *"What should the reserves be in order to get X amount of output tokens by exchanging Y amount of input tokens"*.

**What I've tried:**

We know that **reserveIn * reserveOut = k**, which should be constant. This means that **reserveOut = k / reserveIn**, so we can substitute that in our original algorithm:

```
amountOut = k / reserveIn * amountIn * 9975 / (reserveIn * 10000 + amountIn * 9975)
```

Solving for **reserveIn** gives us:

```
reserveIn = (-amountIn * 9975 * amountOutMin + sqrt(amountIn * 9975 * amountIn * 9975 * amountOutMin * amountOutMin + 4 * k * amountIn * 9975 * 10000 * amountOutMin)) / (2 * 10000 * amountOutMin)
```

Afterwards we can get the **reserveOut** value using:

```
reserveOut = k / newReserveIn
```

However, the above is not entirely accurate. There's still a percentage of error from the correct result. Additionally, since I'm looking to execute this algorithm from solidity, the above algorithm also poses the following problems:

1. Overflow - the result of some mathematical expressions exceeds what can fit in a uint256
2. The square root operation will result in some accuracy loss.

The questions that I have are:

1. How can the algorithm be corrected so that there is no error? Is there a better algorithm to accurately calculate the reserves?
2. Can such an algorithm be implemented that keeps the results of expressions within the range of a uint256 and without using square roots?

Comment: k is constant if you don't take the fees into account (with the fees, each trade increases k) + pay attention to the difference between pancake (0.25% -> the 9975 that you use) and uniswap (0.3%)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need answer to this but the easiest way to do this is to get the pair contract via the pancake swap factory. Note: I am using web3.py so might be slightly different if you use web3.js or anything else but the flow should essentially be the same:

```
#get the factory contract
factoryContract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeFactoryCA,abi = pancakeFactoryABI)

#get the pair contract address:
pairCA = factory.functions.getPair(token1CA,token2CA).call()

#Get the pair contract:
pairContract = web3.eth.contract(address=pairCA, abi = pairABI)

#get the reserve from the pair:
(reserve1,reserve2,timestamp) = pairContract.functions.getReserves().call()
```

For the pairABI you can take it from any pancakeswap pair, they all have the getReserve function.

You can find pancake factory address and ABI here: https://bscscan.com/address/0xbcfccbde45ce874adcb698cc183debcf17952812